# Localization not working (in my app) with windows phone toolkit's date picker

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, silverlight-toolkit

I need the picker page from the toolkit's datepicker control to be in spanish. I tried a few approaches found here on SO, but they didn't work for me.

One thing a noticed is that when i run the sample app from the toolkit, the picker page is localized, but when i run my app which uses the same dll, it does not.

So the question is, what is doing the sample app, that mine doesn't in order for the picker page to be localized?

My DatePicker declaration:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Width="280" Background="#96CA04" Foreground="White"  Value="    {Binding LeagueBegDate,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

Sample App DAtePicker declaration:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker ValueChanged="DatePicker_ValueChanged"/>
```

Comment: check the Resources folder inside the sample project

Comment: @verdesrobert I did look for a "resources.lang.resx" file, but there's none in the sample app, nor there is a Resources folder. But now that i look, what i did found, was a LocalizedResources Folder in the **toolkit project**, which contains the right strings. But if they are in the DLL, Why don't they work in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i had to do was, to open the *.csproj* file of my project and add **es-ES;** entry under the `<SupportedCultures>`  node.

I did try adding just **es;**, but it didn't work. It had to be **es-ES;** as in the toolkit project, under the LocalizedResources folder the resx files is called: **ControlResources.es-ES.resx**.

So the entry ended up looking like this:

```
<SupportedCultures>
    es; es-ES;
</SupportedCultures>
```

To clarify, i did not have to add a localized resources file in my project, just added the supported cultures and the toolkit's localization kicked in.